# showPermissionDialog with ExternalInterface (facebook/ flash)

Tags: flash, facebook, externalinterface

I trying to pomp showPermissionDialog for allow the user to post something in a friend Wall.

I have the flowing javascript code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function showStreamPermissions() {
    FB.Connect.showPermissionDialog("publish_stream", doResult);    
     }
 </script>
```

On may as3 class file i have this code to call  showStreamPermissions:

```
protected function showPermissionDialog(e:MouseEvent):void {

  ExternalInterface.call("showStreamPermissions");

  }
```

But when i click the button to show Premonition Dialog , nothing happens?

Does anyone know why ?

Thanks.

MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I  figure what was the problem. It´s necessary to  allow script access

params.allowScriptAccess="always";